# On Windows 2008 R2, how do I back up DHCP if the DHCP .mdb database is always busy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, dhcp

I get this from my backup software.

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\dhcp\dhcp.mdb : The process cannot access the
  file because it is being used by another process.
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\dhcp\j50.log : The process cannot access the file
  because it is being used by another process.
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\dhcp\j50tmp.log : The process cannot access the
  file because it is being used by another process.
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\dhcp\tmp.edb : The process cannot access the file
  because it is being used by another process.

My questions:

- Should I be doing a manual backup of DHCP via command line tools or maybe with MMC, Action, Backup before I run my backup?
- Is the  %SystemRoot%\System32\DHCP\Backup directory always kept up to
  date? (which does get backed up by backup software)  I'm answering my own question but the registry key is set up for 3c, 60 minutes, I believe. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCPServer\Parameters\BackupInterva

This is not the included backup software for Windows.  It is another product, but I have seen this with every backup software I've ever used.

Comment: By default, the DHCP database is backed up every 60 minutes automatically. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff621490.aspx), So yes exclude the active files but backup the backup files. Also make note of having to do an extra restore step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your backup software provide a way to backup the system state information?  The system state includes a copy of the DHCP database.

Comment: It does, but I could not verify that system state includes the DHCP database.  I saw it does the roles, but not the actual data.  Do you have a link for that, so I can document it?  I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be explicitly documented anywhere that I can find, but I just verified that the system state backup of my dhcp server does include the DHCP database.

Comment: I verified by expanding out the "system state" selection within my backup software, among other items, DHCP is listed.  Your backup software may have documentation on how to check this.